# `if __name__ == '__main__'` equivalent in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, program-entry-point

I am new to Ruby.  I'm looking to import functions from a module that contains a tool I want to continue using separately.  In Python I would simply do this:

```
def a():
    ...
def b():
    ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a()
    b()
```

This allows me to run the program or import it as a module to use `a()` and/or `b()` separately.  What's the equivalent paradigm in Ruby?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run a Ruby library from the command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487086/run-a-ruby-library-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 151, accepted):

From the Ruby I've seen out in the wild (granted, not a ton), this is not a standard Ruby design pattern. Modules and scripts are supposed to stay separate, so I wouldn't be surprised if there isn't really a good, clean way of doing this.

**EDIT:** [Found it.](http://gimbo.org.uk/blog/2006/04/18/scripts-in-ruby-a-la-pythons-__name__-__main__-idiom/)

```
if __FILE__ == $0
    foo()
    bar()
end
```

But it's definitely not common.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind keeping modules and scripts separate, out of curiosity?

Comment: I think it's just what Rubyists prefer to do. A module definition is a module definition. If you want to take some action with that module, fine, but the action you're taking *isn't* a module definition.

Comment: It's handy, though, for testing things -- you can put module tests in there and run them just from the module file without any wrapper.

Comment: @Imagist and @ebneter

Or the other way around: the script is a single module that is intended to be run from the commandline, but you also want to be able to test it in parts and have the test in a seperate module. In that case, __NAME__ == $0 is invaluable.

Comment: I haven't seen this either, but it isn't frowned upon. The official Ruby docs use it: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/4/

Comment: I'd use File.expand_path(path) on them to take into account things like ./my-program or running it from another directory...

Comment: Perfectly standard solution as for today. But  **`$PROGRAM_NAME`** is preferred over `$0` in conformity with **The Ruby Style Guide** https://rubystyle.guide/#no-cryptic-perlisms

Answer (score 12):

If stack trace is empty, we can start executing to the right and left. I don't know if that's used conventionally or unconventionally since I'm into Ruby for about a week.

```
if caller.length == 0
  # do stuff
end
```

Proof of concept:

file: test.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby                                                                 

if caller.length == 0
  puts "Main script"
end

puts "Test"
```

file: shmest.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -I .                                                            

require 'test.rb'

puts "Shmest"
```

Usage:

```
$ ./shmest.rb 
Test
Shmest

$ ./test.rb
Main script
Test
```

Answer (score 12):

```
if $PROGRAM_NAME == __FILE__
  foo()
  bar()
end
```

is preferred by [Rubocop](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/GlobalVars) over this:

```
if __FILE__ == $0
    foo()
    bar()
end
```