# Run program from console independently from tests

Tags: ruby

I have a program that's supposed to run in the console. In a file called `my_program.rb` I have:

```
class MyProgram
end
MyProgram.new.start
```

I also have a separate `my_program_test.rb` and everytime I want to run the tests I need to comment out `MyProgram.new.start` to avoid running the program in the console.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no ruby expert, but I believe you could use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2249332/1095379):

```
if __FILE__ == $0
    MyProgram.new.start
end
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! I'll accept you answer a soon as SO lets me.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

With RSpec you can stub the `start` method before the tests that would trigger it. Something like:

```
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(MyProgram).to receive(:start).and_return(true)
end
```