# Can I write Ruby code that is executed only when my script is run, but not when it is required?

Tags: ruby

I want to write a Ruby script something like this:

```
class Foo
  # instance methods here

  def self.run
    foo = Foo.new
    # do stuff here
  end
end

# This code should only be executed when run as a script, but not when required into another file
unless required_in?  # <-- not a real Kernel method
  Foo.run
end
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to be able to unit test it, which is why I don't want the code outside of the class to run unless I execute the script directly, i.e. `ruby foo_it_up.rb`.

I know I can simply put the `Foo` class in another file and `require 'foo'` in my script. In fact, that is probably a better way to do it, just in case `Foo`'s functionality is needed somewhere else. So my question is more academic than anything, but I'd still be interested in knowing how to do this in Ruby.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run a Ruby library from the command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487086/run-a-ruby-library-from-the-command-line) - but it took some serious Googling to find it! I'm surprised this question isn't asked more often.

Comment: Andrew: Same here. I expected to find the answer on Stack Overflow already! Thanks for your help, again.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is usually done with

```
if __FILE__ == $0
  Foo.run
end
```

but I prefer

```
if File.identical?(__FILE__, $0)
  Foo.run
end
```

because programs like ruby-prof [can make $0 not equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335942/is-there-a-better-way-to-make-ruby-profs-replace-progname-work-properly)  `__FILE__` even when you use `--replace-progname`.

`$0` refers to the name of the program (`$PROGRAM_NAME`), while `__FILE__` is the name of the current source file.

Comment: Very straight-forward. Thanks!