# Run code only if script called from the command line

Tags: ruby, command-line

So when I call my script from the command line, I want it to take in an int and do something with the value:

```
ruby script.rb


puts ARGV[0], etc...
```

However, whenever the script is loaded or required and not called from command line, I want to completely skip this part of the code. How can I detect whether the script has been called via command line, or just loaded? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run a Ruby library from the command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487086/run-a-ruby-library-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It is common to put this at the bottom of your script:

```
if __FILE__==$0
  # this will only run if the script was the main, not load'd or require'd
end
```

Because I like to see the main action at the top of my file, I usually put a `def run!` as the first method in the file and then end the file with:

```
run! if __FILE__==$0
```

Comment: Rubocop told me to change it to 
`if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME` ;)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why `run!` with the bang and not just `run`? Isn't it Ruby convention that the bang is used to indicate that the input object is altered?

Comment: @ScottSchupbach it is a common misconception that Ruby uses `!` for mutating methods. Though it is true that some mutating methods end in `!`, the real guideline (and that's all it is) is to use it if the method is 'dangerous' or 'surprising'. Consider `exit!`, for example. In this case, I'm following neither definition. I like it here because it helps the method stand out as different from other helper methods I may write.

Comment: Is there any way to tell if the file was required rather than eval'd? That seems like it's a much cleaner approach than checking argv for the file name.

Comment: The convention is to use the `!` for methods which are dangerous *and for which a non-dangerous equivalent exists*. cf. http://davidablack.net/dablog.html#2007/8/15/bang-methods-or-danger-will-rubyist

Comment: How about `exit if __FILE__ != $PROGRAM_NAME` ?