# Command line script that runs a method only when it is executed?

Tags: ruby, command-line

I am building a gem for command line use, and I am aware of the `if __FILE__ == $0` method for determining whether the file being run is the current file (from [Run code only if script called from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990790/run-code-only-if-script-called-from-the-command-line?rq=1)), however this doesn't work in my case. I have a module with an initialize function that I would like to run when the gem is called from the command line.

```
module MyApp
    def self.initialize
        # do command line stuff
    end
    def self.test
        # run a rake test
    end
end

MyApp::initialize
```

However, when running `rake test` it calls the initialize function which returns an error:

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/myapp ❤ rake test
Options:
    -v, --[no-]verbose               Run verbosely
    -h, --help                       Show this message
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (255): [ruby -I"lib" -I"/Users/bbriggs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib" "/Users/bbriggs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/test_myapp.rb" ]
/Users/bbriggs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/bbriggs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I think this is because I am doing `MyApp:initialize`, because if I take that out of my code the `rake test` runs as expected, but the command line tool no longer works.

At the moment I am testing my app via `bundle exec bin/myapp`, and printing out the `__FILE__` and `$0` variables give me `bin/myapp` and `path/to/lib/myapp.rb` respectively, so I was wondering what the best way is to detect whether the module is being required or called directly. Am I even doing this right? I'm a bit of a Ruby newbie. :-)

Comment: `whether the module is being required or called directly` as opposed to what?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by `initialize function which returns an error because there are no parameters being sent from the command line`.

Comment: I've updated the question, to clarify.

Comment: I don't see where you are using the `__FILE__ == $0` code that you mention.

Comment: I'm putting that at the bottom of the script, but because `__FILE__ `and `$0` do not equal the same thing it doesn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out. Instead of running `MyApp:initialize` in `lib/myapp.rb` I put it in the `bin/myapp` file. This ensures that it is only run when the app is run from the command line and not when being tested via Rake or required by another script.